# Замена url youtube на фрейм с видео в Sublime text 3 в html

Tags: html

Всем привет знатоки!
У меня есть такие строки текста, как:

`<a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pahhmV4WUUU">`

Мне нужно сделать заменить в sublime text 3, например:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pahhmV4WUUU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

То есть не трогать pahhmV4WUUU и таких ссылок очень много

Сломал голову как это сделать уже, пробовал регулярки но пока не получается!

Answer (score 0):

Ищем:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=(\w+)">
```

Замена:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/\1" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

*В `notepad++` сработало*